# jquery number counter animation triggered by scroll value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, numbers

So im trying to make a counter that is triggered by a certain scroll value,
in other words, i want the users to see animated numbers going from 0 to a specified number once they reach a certain scroll value

and this is what i go so far:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){

    var _scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();

    if(_scrollTop >= 1490){
        $('.Count').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
                jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.text() }, {
                    duration: 3000,
                    easing: 'swing',
                    step: function () {
                        $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter)).stop();
                    }
                });
        }); 
    }
});
```

But the numbers keep refreshing every time i scroll above that value,
I wanted it to animate it once when the user scrolls above that value and then remain on the specified value on the html
Thank you very much for your help

[Full site Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V4TLr/1/)

Comment: please try to provide a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the scroll function doesn't have to run again, after the first time the criteria is met (counter is started), you could choose to unbind the function completely:

```
if(_scrollTop >= 1490){
    $(document).unbind('scroll');
    //......
```

That will unbind all bound scroll events on document, if you implement multiple scroll events, you can store the specific delegate in a variable and unbind that.